# react-native adding crashlytics

Tags: crashlytics, react-native-firebase

I'm new to react-native . 
I'm trying to add crashlytics to my app , this is my podfile:

```
# Required by RNFirebase
pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> 5.15.0'
pod 'Firebase/Auth', '~> 5.15.0'
pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.9.0'
pod 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.12.0'
pod 'GoogleIDFASupport', '~> 3.14.0'
```

this is my code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native';
import {Provider} from "mobx-react";
import rootStore from './src/stores/RootStore';
import firebase from "react-native-firebase";

class App extends Component {

componentDidMount(){
    firebase.crashlytics().enableCrashlyticsCollection();
}

render() {

    return (
        <Provider rootStore={rootStore}>
            <View/>
        </Provider>

    )}
}


export default (App);
```

I get this error message :

`371d29ab-9482-42bd-a…-4915912912cd:25629 Error: You attempted to use a firebase module that's not installed natively on your iOS project by calling firebase.crashlytics(). Ensure you have the required Firebase iOS SDK pod for this module included in your Podfile, in this instance confirm you've added "pod 'undefined'" to your Podfile`

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Just like you, I got the same issue today... even if it works before like a charm.

Strange, don't know how it came out of the blue!?!

I figured out, that if I open XCode -> Product -> Scheme and duplicate the Scheme and set Build-Configuration on that duplicated Scheme to Release, the Error didn't appear.

I've even tried to remove /ios/Pods and reinstall all the Pods. Didn't get it to work in Debug-Mode. Any Idea why?

[image]